# Where can I stay in a castle in northern Wales?

Tags: uk, accommodation, architecture, wales

Where can I stay in a castle in northern Wales, specifically in the Snowdonia Natioal Park, Anglesey or Caernafon-Llandudno areas (not sure of the official name of this area)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually several, as found in a quick google search.  But one that matches your area certainly seems to be [Bodelwyddan Castle](http://www.warnerleisurehotels.co.uk/hotels/bodelwyddan-castle-hotel/overview/). It is just under an hour from Chester, 10 minutes from the seaside town of Rhyl, and half an hour away from the Victorian Pier at Llandudno.

[image]

A similarly close one is [Ruthin Castle Hotel](http://www.ruthincastle.co.uk/), although it's a bit closer to the Chester side of North Wales.

[image]

I believe the area names you're looking for might be Denbighshire, which both these castles are located in.

Comment: I'd seen one in a travel program but I could only find Ruthin in my Googling, which didn't look quite right.  Looks like there might be more to choose from than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mark's suggestions, there's [Bryn Bras Castle](http://www.brynbrascastle.co.uk/), 10 minutes drive from Snowdonia National Park and Caernafon.

[image]

And also [Glandyfi Castle](http://www.glandyficastle.co.uk/) on the southern edge of Snowdownia National Park.

[image]